# Cloudformation to automatically pick up the default instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I use a CloudFormation template to deploy an instance to the environment. I want the template to pick up the default EC2 instance profile for the instance which is something like "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/EC2InstanceProfile-InstanceRole-14F2A0ATJNUO1"

I would like to use the same template for every AWS accounts I have. However, the problem is that the instance profile name is different in every account. A randomly generated suffix is attached to the name (in this example 14F2A0ATJNUO1). How can I workaround this problem to make the template reusable in every account. Please provide the code if possible.

```
    "EC2InstanceProfile" : {
      "Description" : "The default instance profile",
      "Type": "String",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing defualt EC2 instance profile."
    },

"IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "EC2InstanceProfile" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Get your instance profile from the role name using the below cloudformation.

```
"InstanceProfile" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
  "Properties" : {
    "Path" : "/",
    "Roles" : ["your-role-name"]
  }
}
"IamInstanceProfile": {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["InstanceProfile", "Arn"] },
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't answer my question. The instance profile is already created. So the template needs to pick up the instance profile. I can hardcode the name "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/EC2InstanceProfile-InstanceRole-14F2A0ATJNUO1" but the template wont work in other accounts as the instance role has a random suffix.

Comment: ok. we can create new InstanceProfile as it might not impact any functionality. Or you can use InstanceProfile  input as parameter to cloudformation to reuse the template.

Comment: You must fetch the IamInstanceProfile value via Ref.